# Jackson mapper expands LocalDate

Tags: json, java-8, jackson-modules, jackson2

We have a DTO defined with a LocalDate:

```
@JsonProperty("dob")
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
private LocalDate dob;
```

We have code with an ObjectMapper defined as follows:

```
private static final ObjectMapper makeMapper() {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.registerModule(new ParameterNamesModule());
    mapper.registerModule(new Jdk8Module());
    mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
    return mapper;
}
```

We have all the jackson-datababindm core, jsr310 in our pom.xml file:

```
    <!-- Jackson JSON Mapping -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-module-parameter-names</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jdk8</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.8</version>
    </dependency>
```

So, when I convert my object to a JSON string:

```
    String json = makeMapper().writeValueAsString(myobject);
```

The dob writes to the JSON string as:

"dob":{
      "year": 1964,
      "month": "FEBRUARY",
      "chronology": {
          "calendarType": "iso8601",
          "id": "ISO"
      },
      "monthValue": 2,
      "dayOfMonth": 13,
      "dayOfWeek": "THURSDAY",
      "era": "CE",
       "dayOfYear": 44,
       "leapYear": true}

instead of:   "dob":"1964-02-13"   which is correct.

So, I am not sure how I made this happen?
I'd like to make sure the date gets written out correct, so I can re-parse back to a LocalDate.   Or, is there a way I can take the existing JSON (expanded) and parse that back to a LocalDate?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using JAX-RS and one of its implementations?

Comment: I tried out your code in a new project with these dependencies in `pom.xml` and it worked fine. I could only see the output you see if I didn't register `JavaTimeModule`. I suggest you review what other config you may have in your project or other annotations in the class that contains the `dob` field

Comment: We're using Spring-WS, and not using any JAX-RS that I am aware of.

Comment: We absolutely are adding JavaTimeModule to our ObjectMapper. The definition is as we described above.    I'll keep looking into this for sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out this was a ClassLoader issue.  In the smallest case, the code works and the LocalDate is turned into JSON accordingly.  When you emebed one project into another into another, then what happens is that the ObjectMapper was defined elsewhere without the JavaTimeModule.

I took the code:

```
private static final ObjectMapper makeMapper() {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.registerModule(new ParameterNamesModule());
    mapper.registerModule(new Jdk8Module());
    mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
    return mapper;
}
```

and brought it right into my class where I needed it, and that worked.   Reaching out to a utility from a different project didn't work for me.

Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 3):

Within `com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.7` could achieve the `LocalDate` workaround with the following code:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
String expectedJson = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(dataVersions);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Import dependence: jackson-datatype-jsr310
2. Write an extension class: JsonJacksonCodecExt

```java
package org.wjw.redisson;

import org.redisson.codec.JsonJacksonCodec;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.JavaTimeModule;

/** 对 {@link org.redisson.codec.JsonJacksonCodec} 的扩展,是的其能支持LocalDate
 * The Class JsonJacksonCodecExt.
 */
public class JsonJacksonCodecExt extends JsonJacksonCodec{
  @Override
  protected void init(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
    objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
    objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
    
    super.init(objectMapper);    
  }
  
}
```

3. Test code

```java
  @Test
  void testRMap_PutGet_JsonStringCodec() {
    RMap<String, User> map = redisson.getMap("jsonMap",new JsonJacksonCodecExt());
    map.put("1", new User("wjw1", 18, LocalDate.now()));
    map.put("2", new User("wjw2", 19, LocalDate.now()));
    map.put("3", new User("wjw3", 20, LocalDate.now()));

    User v = map.get("2");

    System.out.println(v);
  }
```